# migrate unidata database which is multivalue to sql using dotnet code

Tags: data-migration, u2, unidata, uniobjects, u2netdk

i want to migrate unidata database which is multivalue to sql using dotnet code.IS this possible,one of the possibility is through SSIS but this will consume lot of time becouse we have to do ETL process to all the tables in DB .So was looking for a dot net code where i can connect to Unidatadb and migrate data to sql

Answer (score 0):

You're probably getting downvoted because this is an awfully general question, and it's not particularly a programming question, but rather a big project.

One piece of advice is to flip things around and extract the information from the Unidata side "exploding" out the multivalues into flat tables that your ETL process can consume.  And the challenge there (apart from writing Unibasic code) is identifying which multivalued fields are associated with each other.  Unless you have very good documentation that can be tough to do.